# Wcf HTTP and HTTPS on the same host/port

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

Hello,

I know how to create a self hosted wcf for http or https, but not at the same time.

I would like a wcf for this 2 urls :

1. https:// 127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/
2. http:// 127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/

At the moment I have the configuration for https (with a certificate: makecert + netsh) and it works fine:

**app.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ProxySips_Wcf.Sips" behaviorConfiguration="ProxySips_Wcf.ProxySipsBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/"   />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
              contract="ProxySips_Wcf.ISips"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProxySips_Wcf.ProxySipsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Host**

```
var serviceType = typeof(ProxySips_Wcf.Sips);
var host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);
host.Open();
```

Can help me set up the http version for the same address?

Many thanks

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Im trying to figure out if WCF can listen for http and https on the same URI/port at the same time, or not. So far, I havent managed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the use of [Multiple Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With multiple endpoints you can support the same service over multiple protocols (HTTP and HTTPS in your case).

So you will need to add the following `ServiceBehavior`:

```
<behavior name="MyUnsecureServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
</behavior>
```

Then the following `Binding`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name= MyUnsecureBindingConfig"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 messageEncoding="Text">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                   maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                   maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     <security mode="None">
         <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
         <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
     </security>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

And lastly the following `Address` configuration:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyUnsecureServiceBehavior"
                         name="MyUnsecureService">
   <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/"
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             contract="ProxySips_Wcf.ISips"
             bindingConfiguration="MyUnsecureBindingConfig" />
   <endpoint address="mex"
             binding="mexHttpBinding"
             contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

**UPDATE:**

On your `WCF Host` application, you will need to specify the new URI to listen at. You can set up your host similar to this:

```
var httpsAddress = new Uri("https:// 127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/");
var httpAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:13070/ProxySips/");
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProxySips_Wcf.Sips), 
                            new Uri[] { httpsAddress, httpAddress });
host.Open();
```

Comment: Hello Derek,Thanks for your help but when I put your configuration, I have no error on execution, but nothing happens on the http endpoint. Should I create a new host service?

Comment: @Bob: I updated my answer with how to specify the multiple endpoints for your host application to listen at. Let me know either way.