# WCF REST service HTTP/HTTPS port sharing

Tags: rest, http, wcf, https, wcf-binding

I'm trying to configure a WCF REST service to be accessible using HTTP as well as using HTTPS.

Since this is an in production service I would like to minimize the changes required to get HTTPS up and running. I would like to achieve a solution in which the admin only needs to replace the **http://** with **https://**. According to this [Wcf HTTP and HTTPS on the same host/port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992136/wcf-http-and-https-on-the-same-host-port) it should be possible to achieve this but I'm struggling with the configuration.

```
<services>
    <service name="My.Server">      
        <!-- HTTP services -->
        <endpoint address="/Common/"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restEndpointBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="My.IServer" />      
        <!-- HTTPS services -->
        <endpoint address="/Common/"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restEndpointBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="httpsBindingConfiguration"
                  contract="My.IServer" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/MyService" />
                <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8732/MyService" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
</services>
```

Everything works fine as long as I'm just using either the HTTP or the HTTPS binding (tested using Postman) but as soon as I activate both endpoints the service startup fails stating:

### Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL https://+:8732/MyService/Common/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'https://+:8732/MyService/Common/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

I'm aware of all the ***netsh http urlacl|sslcert*** stuff and can confirm that those should not be an issue since using only one endpoint (either HTTP or HTTPS) or changing the port for HTTPS e.g. **:8733** fixes the issue and the service reponds as expected but as stated earlier I would like to use the same ports.

After researching and trying for quite some time now my guess is that such a configuration is not supported. Can anybody confirm my guess or does know a way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You know those `endpoints` should uses different `bindingConfiguration` as you have done it, I setup `http` and `https` for a service on port `80` and they are working nice but before anything I defined the configuration like below:

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding allowCookies="true" openTimeout="00:00:10" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
    <security mode="None" />
  </binding>
  <binding name="secureWebHttpBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

and then defining `endpoints` like:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Commom2.Behavior" name="name"> 
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="x">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="x">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost/serviceName.svc" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

Note:
I enabled `https` binding and uploaded valid certificate there and I have configur-ed one `baseAddresses` on `http` as you can see in config but that service is accessible on `http://localhost/serviceName.svc/rest` and `https://localhost/serviceName.svc/rest`

Your problem may because of having two `baseAddresses` and wrong port registered for `https`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aria. You are running your service through IIS right? Unfortunately I'm running the service in a Self-Hosted scenario (Windows service) so I do not have a webserver in front of WCF.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688342/windows-service-hosted-wcf-over-https

Comment: Just checked your link but it does not really relay to my problem since I try to accomplish a port sharing (in my example :8732) whereas Rob tries to run a service using the HTTPS protocol. I've got HTTPS up and running but I need to use another port e.g :8733